# c# Image resizing to different size while preserving aspect ratio

Tags: c#, image-processing, system.drawing, image-scaling

I'm trying to resize an image while preserving the aspect ratio from the original image so the new image doesn't look squashed.

eg:

> Convert a 150*100 image into a 150*150 image.
>   The extra 50 pixels of the height need to be padded with a white background color.

This is the current code I am using.

It works well for resizing but changing the aspect ratio of the original image squashes the new image.

```
private void resizeImage(string path, string originalFilename, 
                         int width, int height)
    {
        Image image = Image.FromFile(path + originalFilename);

        System.Drawing.Image thumbnail = new Bitmap(width, height);
        System.Drawing.Graphics graphic = 
                     System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(thumbnail);

        graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        graphic.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        graphic.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

        graphic.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);

        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo[] info =
                         ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
        EncoderParameters encoderParameters;
        encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
        encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality,
                         100L);            
        thumbnail.Save(path + width + "." + originalFilename, info[1], 
                         encoderParameters);
    }
```

EDIT: I'd like to have the image padded instead of cropped

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I found out how to resize AND pad the image by learning from this [this CodeProject Article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/imageresize.aspx).

```
static Image FixedSize(Image imgPhoto, int Width, int Height)
    {
        int sourceWidth = imgPhoto.Width;
        int sourceHeight = imgPhoto.Height;
        int sourceX = 0;
        int sourceY = 0;
        int destX = 0;
        int destY = 0;

        float nPercent = 0;
        float nPercentW = 0;
        float nPercentH = 0;

        nPercentW = ((float)Width / (float)sourceWidth);
        nPercentH = ((float)Height / (float)sourceHeight);
        if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
        {
            nPercent = nPercentH;
            destX = System.Convert.ToInt16((Width -
                          (sourceWidth * nPercent)) / 2);
        }
        else
        {
            nPercent = nPercentW;
            destY = System.Convert.ToInt16((Height -
                          (sourceHeight * nPercent)) / 2);
        }

        int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
        int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

        Bitmap bmPhoto = new Bitmap(Width, Height,
                          PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        bmPhoto.SetResolution(imgPhoto.HorizontalResolution,
                         imgPhoto.VerticalResolution);

        Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto);
        grPhoto.Clear(Color.Red);
        grPhoto.InterpolationMode =
                InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        grPhoto.DrawImage(imgPhoto,
            new Rectangle(destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight),
            new Rectangle(sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight),
            GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        grPhoto.Dispose();
        return bmPhoto;
    }
```

Comment: @bobek just close the original image
imgPhoto.Dispose();

Comment: Nice code! Even cleaner if using 'using pattern' for Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto);    and    sourceX and sourceY variables discarded and set to 0 literal in  'new Rectangle(0, 0, sourceWidth, sourceHeight)'

Comment: exactly what I needed ;) especially helpful when you need to pass an image parameter instead of the actual path.

Comment: Good code, however I suggest to use Color.White rather than Color.Red

Comment: Is there anyway to set the `Graphis grPhoto` size to match the new physical size of the image? I would like to avoid having a background color at all.

Answer (score 134):

This should do it.

```
private void resizeImage(string path, string originalFilename, 
                     /* note changed names */
                     int canvasWidth, int canvasHeight, 
                     /* new */
                     int originalWidth, int originalHeight)
{
    Image image = Image.FromFile(path + originalFilename);

    System.Drawing.Image thumbnail = 
        new Bitmap(canvasWidth, canvasHeight); // changed parm names
    System.Drawing.Graphics graphic = 
                 System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(thumbnail);

    graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    graphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    graphic.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    graphic.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

    /* ------------------ new code --------------- */

    // Figure out the ratio
    double ratioX = (double) canvasWidth / (double) originalWidth;
    double ratioY = (double) canvasHeight / (double) originalHeight;
    // use whichever multiplier is smaller
    double ratio = ratioX < ratioY ? ratioX : ratioY;

    // now we can get the new height and width
    int newHeight = Convert.ToInt32(originalHeight * ratio);
    int newWidth = Convert.ToInt32(originalWidth * ratio);

    // Now calculate the X,Y position of the upper-left corner 
    // (one of these will always be zero)
    int posX = Convert.ToInt32((canvasWidth - (originalWidth * ratio)) / 2);
    int posY = Convert.ToInt32((canvasHeight - (originalHeight * ratio)) / 2);

    graphic.Clear(Color.White); // white padding
    graphic.DrawImage(image, posX, posY, newWidth, newHeight);

    /* ------------- end new code ---------------- */

    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo[] info =
                     ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
    EncoderParameters encoderParameters;
    encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
    encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality,
                     100L);            
    thumbnail.Save(path + newWidth + "." + originalFilename, info[1], 
                     encoderParameters);
}
```

**Edited to add:**

Those who want to improve this code should put it in the comments, or a new answer. Don't edit this code directly.

Comment: Just wondering about the parameters originalWidth and originalHeight, why do you need them when you can just get that info from image?  (I did edit your code in the past, before I had permission to comment, my apologies for that)

Comment: @mendel - yes, that would work as well. But in the original question he already knew the height & width, so why recalculate them again?

Comment: i tried this on a 1024*768 image to convert to 500*500 one - the image gets distorted. I am looking for algorithm like that of wordpress CMS where the images are not distorted when they are made smaller size (however some cropping from the sides are there).

Comment: @yogihosting post a question with your problem, including your code, maybe even a link to a test image. This is working for other people, so we'll need to see what's different for you.

Comment: @egrunin I suggest using `Path.Combine(path, originalFileName)` when loading the original image. Same when saving the thumbnail at the end.

Answer (score 37):

I use the following method to calculate the desired image size:

```
using System.Drawing;
public static Size ResizeKeepAspect(this Size src, int maxWidth, int maxHeight, bool enlarge = false)
{
    maxWidth = enlarge ? maxWidth : Math.Min(maxWidth, src.Width);
    maxHeight = enlarge ? maxHeight : Math.Min(maxHeight, src.Height);

    decimal rnd = Math.Min(maxWidth / (decimal)src.Width, maxHeight / (decimal)src.Height);
    return new Size((int)Math.Round(src.Width * rnd), (int)Math.Round(src.Height * rnd));
}
```

This puts the problem of aspect ratio and dimensions in a separate method.

*What does the parameter* `bool enlarge = false` ?

usually you do only shrinking of images because enlarging means quality loss - so I added this optional parameter if you want to do it anyway

Comment: What if I want to do a "fill"? Is that what `enlarge` does?

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen usually you do only shrinking of images because enlarging means quality loss - so I added this optional parameter if you want to do it anyway

Answer (score 11):

To get a faster result, the function that obtains the size could be found in `resultSize`:

```
Size original = new Size(640, 480);

int maxSize = 100;

float percent = (new List<float> { (float)maxSize / (float)original.Width , (float)maxSize  / (float)original.Height }).Min();

Size resultSize = new Size((int)Math.Floor(original.Width * percent), (int)Math.Floor(original.Height * percent));
```

Uses `Linq` to minimize variable and recalculations, as well as unnecesary `if/else` statements

Comment: This is a fantastic solution! Very concise and small. I used a modified version of this along with System.Web.Helpers.WebImage to resize an image proportionally on the fly. Great job!

Comment: ```If/else``` would have been better than allocating a list, ```Math.Min``` too was an option

Answer (score 7):

Just generalizing it down to aspect ratios and sizes, image stuff can be done outside of this function

```
public static d.RectangleF ScaleRect(d.RectangleF dest, d.RectangleF src, 
  bool keepWidth, bool keepHeight)  
{
    d.RectangleF destRect = new d.RectangleF();

    float sourceAspect = src.Width / src.Height;
    float destAspect = dest.Width / dest.Height;

    if (sourceAspect > destAspect)
    {
        // wider than high keep the width and scale the height
        destRect.Width = dest.Width;
        destRect.Height = dest.Width / sourceAspect;

        if (keepHeight)
        {
            float resizePerc = dest.Height / destRect.Height;
            destRect.Width = dest.Width * resizePerc;
            destRect.Height = dest.Height;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // higher than wide – keep the height and scale the width
        destRect.Height = dest.Height;
        destRect.Width = dest.Height * sourceAspect;

        if (keepWidth)
        {
            float resizePerc = dest.Width / destRect.Width;
            destRect.Width = dest.Width;
            destRect.Height = dest.Height * resizePerc;
        }

    }

    return destRect;
}
```

Comment: That is a great idea separating this concern. You could use [SizeF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.sizef.aspx) instead of `RectangleF`.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to add my code here too. This code will allow you resize an image with or without the aspect ratio being enforced or to resize with padding. This is a modified version of egrunin's code.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var path = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName;
            ResizeImage(path, "large.jpg", path, "new.jpg", 100, 100, true, true);
        }

        /// <summary>Resizes an image to a new width and height.</summary>
        /// <param name="originalPath">The folder which holds the original image.</param>
        /// <param name="originalFileName">The file name of the original image.</param>
        /// <param name="newPath">The folder which will hold the resized image.</param>
        /// <param name="newFileName">The file name of the resized image.</param>
        /// <param name="maximumWidth">When resizing the image, this is the maximum width to resize the image to.</param>
        /// <param name="maximumHeight">When resizing the image, this is the maximum height to resize the image to.</param>
        /// <param name="enforceRatio">Indicates whether to keep the width/height ratio aspect or not. If set to false, images with an unequal width and height will be distorted and padding is disregarded. If set to true, the width/height ratio aspect is maintained and distortion does not occur.</param>
        /// <param name="addPadding">Indicates whether fill the smaller dimension of the image with a white background. If set to true, the white padding fills the smaller dimension until it reach the specified max width or height. This is used for maintaining a 1:1 ratio if the max width and height are the same.</param>
        private static void ResizeImage(string originalPath, string originalFileName, string newPath, string newFileName, int maximumWidth, int maximumHeight, bool enforceRatio, bool addPadding)
        {
            var image = Image.FromFile(originalPath + "\\" + originalFileName);
            var imageEncoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
            EncoderParameters encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
            encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 100L);
            var canvasWidth = maximumWidth;
            var canvasHeight = maximumHeight;
            var newImageWidth = maximumWidth;
            var newImageHeight = maximumHeight;
            var xPosition = 0;
            var yPosition = 0;


            if (enforceRatio)
            {
                var ratioX = maximumWidth / (double)image.Width;
                var ratioY = maximumHeight / (double)image.Height;
                var ratio = ratioX < ratioY ? ratioX : ratioY;
                newImageHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio);
                newImageWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);

                if (addPadding)
                {
                    xPosition = (int)((maximumWidth - (image.Width * ratio)) / 2);
                    yPosition = (int)((maximumHeight - (image.Height * ratio)) / 2);
                }
                else
                {
                    canvasWidth = newImageWidth;
                    canvasHeight = newImageHeight;                  
                }
            }

            var thumbnail = new Bitmap(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
            var graphic = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnail);

            if (enforceRatio && addPadding)
            {
                graphic.Clear(Color.White);
            }

            graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            graphic.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            graphic.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            graphic.DrawImage(image, xPosition, yPosition, newImageWidth, newImageHeight);

            thumbnail.Save(newPath + "\\" + newFileName, imageEncoders[1], encoderParameters);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember to add a reference to the System.Drawing DLL.

Comment: This code rotates the image 90 degrees - the thumbnail is rotated compared to the original - why?

Answer (score 5):

```
// This allows us to resize the image. It prevents skewed images and 
// also vertically long images caused by trying to maintain the aspect 
// ratio on images who's height is larger than their width

public void ResizeImage(string OriginalFile, string NewFile, int NewWidth, int MaxHeight, bool OnlyResizeIfWider)

{
    System.Drawing.Image FullsizeImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(OriginalFile);

    // Prevent using images internal thumbnail
    FullsizeImage.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
    FullsizeImage.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);

    if (OnlyResizeIfWider)
    {
        if (FullsizeImage.Width <= NewWidth)
        {
            NewWidth = FullsizeImage.Width;
        }
    }

    int NewHeight = FullsizeImage.Height * NewWidth / FullsizeImage.Width;
    if (NewHeight > MaxHeight)
    {
        // Resize with height instead
        NewWidth = FullsizeImage.Width * MaxHeight / FullsizeImage.Height;
        NewHeight = MaxHeight;
    }

    System.Drawing.Image NewImage = FullsizeImage.GetThumbnailImage(NewWidth, NewHeight, null, IntPtr.Zero);

    // Clear handle to original file so that we can overwrite it if necessary
    FullsizeImage.Dispose();

    // Save resized picture
    NewImage.Save(NewFile);
}
```

Comment: Did you have an example that doesn't use GetThumbnailImage? I'd like to control the quality and other settings manually.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a less specific extension method that works with Image rather than doing the loading and saving for you. It also allows you to specify interpolation method and correctly renders edges when you use NearestNeighbour interpolation.

The image will be rendered within the bounds of the area you specify so you always know your output width and height. e.g:

[image: Scaled within bounds]

```
namespace YourApp
{
    #region Namespaces
    using System;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Drawing.Imaging;
    using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
    #endregion

    /// <summary>Generic helper functions related to graphics.</summary>
    public static class ImageExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>Resizes an image to a new width and height value.</summary>
        /// <param name="image">The image to resize.</param>
        /// <param name="newWidth">The width of the new image.</param>
        /// <param name="newHeight">The height of the new image.</param>
        /// <param name="mode">Interpolation mode.</param>
        /// <param name="maintainAspectRatio">If true, the image is centered in the middle of the returned image, maintaining the aspect ratio of the original image.</param>
        /// <returns>The new image. The old image is unaffected.</returns>
        public static Image ResizeImage(this Image image, int newWidth, int newHeight, InterpolationMode mode = InterpolationMode.Default, bool maintainAspectRatio = false)
        {
            Bitmap output = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, image.PixelFormat);

            using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(output))
            {
                gfx.Clear(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));
                gfx.InterpolationMode = mode;
                if (mode == InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor)
                {
                    gfx.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                    gfx.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                }

                double ratioW = (double)newWidth / (double)image.Width;
                double ratioH = (double)newHeight / (double)image.Height;
                double ratio = ratioW < ratioH ? ratioW : ratioH;
                int insideWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
                int insideHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio);

                gfx.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle((newWidth / 2) - (insideWidth / 2), (newHeight / 2) - (insideHeight / 2), insideWidth, insideHeight));
            }

            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The parameter for maintainAspectRatio isn't used.

Comment: This works great but as @Haukman pointed out, maintainAspectRatio is not used.

Answer (score 4):

Note: this code resizes and removes everything outside the aspect ratio instead of padding it..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;

namespace MyPhotos.Common
{
    public class ThumbCreator
    {

        public enum VerticalAlign
        {
            Top,
            Middle,
            Bottom
        }

        public enum HorizontalAlign
        {
            Left,
            Middle,
            Right
        }

        public void Convert(string sourceFile, string targetFile, ImageFormat targetFormat, int height, int width, VerticalAlign valign, HorizontalAlign halign)
        {
            using (Image img = Image.FromFile(sourceFile))
            {
                using (Image targetImg = Convert(img, height, width, valign, halign))
                {
                    string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(targetFile);
                    if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
                    }
                    if (targetFormat == ImageFormat.Jpeg)
                    {
                        SaveJpeg(targetFile, targetImg, 100);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        targetImg.Save(targetFile, targetFormat);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary> 
        /// Saves an image as a jpeg image, with the given quality 
        /// </summary> 
        /// <param name="path">Path to which the image would be saved.</param> 
        // <param name="quality">An integer from 0 to 100, with 100 being the 
        /// highest quality</param> 
        public static void SaveJpeg(string path, Image img, int quality)
        {
            if (quality < 0 || quality > 100)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("quality must be between 0 and 100.");


            // Encoder parameter for image quality 
            EncoderParameter qualityParam =
                new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality);
            // Jpeg image codec 
            ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");

            EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
            encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;

            img.Save(path, jpegCodec, encoderParams);
        }

        /// <summary> 
        /// Returns the image codec with the given mime type 
        /// </summary> 
        private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(string mimeType)
        {
            // Get image codecs for all image formats 
            ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();

            // Find the correct image codec 
            for (int i = 0; i < codecs.Length; i++)
                if (codecs[i].MimeType == mimeType)
                    return codecs[i];
            return null;
        }

        public Image Convert(Image img, int height, int width, VerticalAlign valign, HorizontalAlign halign)
        {
            Bitmap result = new Bitmap(width, height);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
            {
                g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                float ratio = (float)height / (float)img.Height;
                int temp = (int)((float)img.Width * ratio);
                if (temp == width)
                {
                    //no corrections are needed!
                    g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
                    return result;
                }
                else if (temp > width)
                {
                    //den e för bred!
                    int overFlow = (temp - width);
                    if (halign == HorizontalAlign.Middle)
                    {
                        g.DrawImage(img, 0 - overFlow / 2, 0, temp, height);
                    }
                    else if (halign == HorizontalAlign.Left)
                    {
                        g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, temp, height);
                    }
                    else if (halign == HorizontalAlign.Right)
                    {
                        g.DrawImage(img, -overFlow, 0, temp, height);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //den e för hög!
                    ratio = (float)width / (float)img.Width;
                    temp = (int)((float)img.Height * ratio);
                    int overFlow = (temp - height);
                    if (valign == VerticalAlign.Top)
                    {
                        g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, width, temp);
                    }
                    else if (valign == VerticalAlign.Middle)
                    {
                        g.DrawImage(img, 0, -overFlow / 2, width, temp);
                    }
                    else if (valign == VerticalAlign.Bottom)
                    {
                        g.DrawImage(img, 0, -overFlow, width, temp);
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Peter This didn't conform to the original defined size width/height that I passed to the function. I got a very slim and long image instead, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @IdanShechter this is a old old old answer(i havent used this code in many many years), could you provide me with a example and i might be able to help you.

Comment: @Peter Thank, I am actually using ImageProcessor, but I get an exception: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51280935/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-when-resizing-image-in-memorystream

Answer (score 3):

I created a extension method that is much simpiler than the answers that are posted.
and the aspect ratio is applied without cropping the image.

```
public static Image Resize(this Image image, int width, int height) {
     var scale = Math.Min(height / (float)image.Height, width / (float)image.Width);
     return image.GetThumbnailImage((int)(image.Width * scale), (int)(image.Height * scale), () => false, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

Example usage:

```
using (var img = Image.FromFile(pathToOriginalImage)) {
    using (var thumbnail = img.Resize(60, 60)){
        // Here you can do whatever you need to do with thumnail
    }
}
```

Comment: It's better if you don't use the ThumbnailImage. Use the image instead.

Comment: The image height and width are not settable in System.Drawing.Image namespace, so you cannot just use the image instead. That only works on old windows forms which is not the same namespace that is being talked about here.

Answer (score 1):

Maintain aspect Ration and eliminate letterbox and Pillarbox.

```
static Image FixedSize(Image imgPhoto, int Width, int Height)
    {
        int sourceWidth = imgPhoto.Width;
        int sourceHeight = imgPhoto.Height;
        int X = 0;
        int Y = 0;

        float nPercent = 0;
        float nPercentW = 0;
        float nPercentH = 0;

        nPercentW = ((float)Width / (float)sourceWidth);
        nPercentH = ((float)Height / (float)sourceHeight);
        if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
        {
            nPercent = nPercentH;
        }
        else
        {
            nPercent = nPercentW;
        }

        int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
        int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

        Bitmap bmPhoto = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        bmPhoto.SetResolution(imgPhoto.HorizontalResolution,
                                         imgPhoto.VerticalResolution);

        Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto);

        grPhoto.DrawImage(imgPhoto,
                new Rectangle(X, Y, destWidth, destHeight),
                new Rectangle(X, Y, sourceWidth, sourceHeight),
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        grPhoto.Dispose();
        return bmPhoto;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void resizeImage_n_save(Stream sourcePath, string targetPath, int requiredSize)
    {
        using (var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(sourcePath))
        {
            double ratio = 0;

            var newWidth = 0;
            var newHeight = 0;
            double w = Convert.ToInt32(image.Width);
            double h = Convert.ToInt32(image.Height);
            if (w > h)
            {
                ratio = h / w * 100;
                newWidth = requiredSize;
                newHeight = Convert.ToInt32(requiredSize * ratio / 100);
            }
            else
            {
                ratio = w / h * 100;
                newHeight = requiredSize;
                newWidth = Convert.ToInt32(requiredSize * ratio / 100);
            }

            //   var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * scaleFactor);
            // var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * scaleFactor);
            var thumbnailImg = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
            var thumbGraph = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnailImg);
            thumbGraph.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            thumbGraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            thumbGraph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            var imageRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

            thumbGraph.DrawImage(image, imageRectangle);
            thumbnailImg.Save(targetPath, image.RawFormat);

            //var img = FixedSize(image, requiredSize, requiredSize);
            //img.Save(targetPath, image.RawFormat);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote this cos none of the answers already here were simple enough. You can replace the hardcoded 128 for whatever you want or base them off the size of the original image. All i wanted was to rescale the image into a 128x128 image, keeping the aspect ratio and centering the result in the new image.

```
    private Bitmap CreateLargeIconForImage(Bitmap src)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(128, 128);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

        float scale = Math.Max((float)src.Width / 128.0f, (float)src.Height / 128.0f);
        PointF p = new PointF(128.0f - ((float)src.Width / scale), 128.0f - ((float)src.Height / scale));
        SizeF size = new SizeF((float)src.Width / scale, (float)src.Height / scale);

        g.DrawImage(src, new RectangleF(p, size));

        return bmp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older thread. However, this is the first result in a Google search on the topic.
None of the answers fit my requirement. So, here's a solution I put together by understanding the older solutions, but limiting the result image size to the most suitable height and width.

```
        double ratioW = (double)desiredWidthPixels / (double)originalImage.Width;
        double ratioH = (double)desiredHeightPixels / (double)originalImage.Height;
        double ratio = ratioW < ratioH ? ratioW : ratioH;
        int suitableWidth = (int)(originalImage.Width * ratio);
        int suitableHeight = (int)(originalImage.Height * ratio);

        var resizedPhoto = new Bitmap((int)suitableWidth, (int)suitableHeight);
        var graphicsSurface = Graphics.FromImage(resizedPhoto);
        graphicsSurface.DrawImage(originalImage, new RectangleF(new PointF(0,0), new SizeF(suitableWidth, suitableHeight)));
```