# Screen resolution problem on drawing rectangle?

Tags: c#

I have drawn rectangle using the screen resolution say (1152x 864). When i change the resolution to (1024x768) the position and height of the drawn rectangle varies.

How to set the rectangle value with different screen resolution...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# Image resizing to different size while preserving aspect ratio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940581/c-image-resizing-to-different-size-while-preserving-aspect-ratio)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) and put all the necessary rows and columns in %. So when the screen resolution changes it will handle accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for replay. Iam new to c# please explain with example.

Thanks

Comment: just add AboutBox.cs is there in add new items for windows forms. which will guide you. add AboutBox.cs as see how it is