# how to resize ratio in image

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I need to resize image,according to the specific aspect ratio.

For example if I have image with this dimensions 1600*800  the ratio is 2:1,

let's say I need to resize the image so the ratio have to be like that 2:3.

Any idea how can I implement it?

Comment: try to read this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940581/c-sharp-image-resizing-to-different-size-while-preserving-aspect-ratio)

Comment: assuming you don't want to stretch the image: you can't just resize as the aspect ratio is different. so you either have to crop or add something or a combination of both. make a diagram on a piece of paper, label the dimensions, work out the geometry and you will have your answer!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just set the width based on the height value * a scalar

```
width = height * 2 //2:1
width = height * 0.66 //2:3
```

Comment: And then use `Image<Gray, Byte> Q_ = Q.Resize(width, height, INTER.CV_INTER_LANCZOS4);` or use the ROI property