# Fit image to ShaderResourceView and preserve aspect ratio

Tags: c#, slimdx

I'm loading an image into a ShaderResourceView to be used as a background image.  This is what I'm currently using:

```
ShaderResourceView.FromFile(_device, imagepath);
```

It loads the image into the background, but it stretches both dimensions without regard to the aspect ratio.  Is there a way to load an image into the background and preserve aspect ratio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally ShaderResourceView would provide a setting to automatically respect the image aspect, but below is the next best option.

An existing post on SO fits the image to a specified size, then pads any extra space with whitespace and creates a new image. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2001462/978622

Another post shows how to easily convert from an Image to a bytearray, which is one of the types ShaderResourceView can create a shader from. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3801289/978622

My code which puts it all together:

```
var original = Image.FromFile(path);
Image resized = FixedSize(original, actualWidth, actualHeight);
var byteImage = ImageToByteArray(resized);
var srv = ShaderResourceView.FromMemory(_device, byteImage);
```