# A generic error occurred in GDI+ when resizing image in MemoryStream

Tags: c#, asp.net, gdi+, memorystream, imageprocessor

I am using [ImageProcessor](http://imageprocessor.org/) to process images in my website.

**I have this resize function**:

```
 public Image ResizePhoto6version(Image img, int width, int height)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var imgf = new ImageFactory(false))
            {
                imgf.Load(img)
                    .Resize(new ResizeLayer(new Size(width, height), ResizeMode.Max))
                    .Save(ms);

                return Bitmap.FromStream(ms);
            }
        }
    }
```

**In the webservice, I run this code**:

```
MemoryStream ytSmallStream = new MemoryStream();
MemoryStream ytMediumStream = new MemoryStream();
System.Drawing.Image ytSmallThumb = null;
System.Drawing.Image ytMediumThumb = null;

ytSmallThumb.Save(ytSmallStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
ytSmallStream.Position = 0;

ytMediumThumb.Save(ytMediumStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
ytMediumStream.Position = 0;
```

I get **an exception** when it reached the Save function ytSmallThumb.Save():

```
A generic error occurred in GDI+
```

The image is returned correctly from ResizeThumbnailToSmall function and the Stream has information of the image with the right size.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your problem is that `FromStream` requires the underlying stream to remain open, yet is being disposed in the `ResizePhoto6version` method (by way of the `using`). From MSDN: "You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image.Save(..) throws a GDI+ exception because the memory stream is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336387/image-save-throws-a-gdi-exception-because-the-memory-stream-is-closed)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I will try that, so I should convert to bytes instead and return that?

Comment: No, just remove the first `using` from the `ResizePhoto6version` method (leave it simply as `var ms=new MemoryStream();`) . It's a memory stream, no *need* to dispose it really. See Jon's answer in the duplicate; just make sure to `Dispose` *the bitmap/image* when you're done and it will close the stream for you

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 correct! Thank you.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33Would you write an answer and I accept?

Comment: No because this is a duplicate. Perhaps there is a better one then the dupe I suggested, but either way this question will eventually  get closed... Its been asked and answered many times before.

Answer (score 1):

ImageProcessor makes me crazy today, it throws "A generic error occurred in GDI+" exception everytime I resize PNG files. and after **Recycle the application pool** I don't see the exception anymore.

Hope it help.